# How to write a shell script that reads all the file names in the directory and finds a particular string in file names?

Tags: shell, scripting, debian-based

I need a shell script to find a string in file like the following one:
FileName_1.00_r0102.tar.gz
And then pick the highest value from multiple occurrences.

I am interested in "1.00" part of the file name. 
I am able to get this part separately in the UNIX shell using the commands:

```
find /directory/*.tar.gz | cut -f2 -d'_' | cut -f1 -d'.'
1
2
3
1
find /directory/*.tar.gz | cut -f2 -d'_' | cut -f2 -d'.'
00
02
05
00
```

The problem is there are multiple files with this string:

FileName_1.01_r0102.tar.gz

FileName_2.02_r0102.tar.gz

FileName_3.05_r0102.tar.gz

FileName_1.00_r0102.tar.gz

I need to pick the file with FileName_("*highest value*")_r0102.tar.gz

But since I am new to shell scripting I am not able to figure out how to handle these multiple instances in script.

The script which I came up with just for the integer part is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /directory/*
file_version = find /directory/*.tar.gz | cut -f2 -d'_' | cut -f1 -d'.'
done
OUTPUT: file_version:command not found
```

Kindly help.
Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer, just an attempt to identify syntax errors, so that you can avoid them next time: 1) you need a `do` in a for loop: `for .... ;do .... ;done`  2) when you set a variable you cannot have spaces around the equals sign: `file_version=5`, *not* `file_version = 5` 3) to set a variable to contain the output of a command, you need [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html): `file_version=$(command)`  4) not a syntax error, but it is a good idea to quote the RHS of a variable assignment: `file_version="$(command)"`.

Comment: Good advice above, but don't make us syntax check your scripts for you, learn to use http://shellcheck.net . Do you know about the `head` and `tail` cmds. That should help if you can force your output to be sorted. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Nick!

Comment: @shellter This was my first time writing a script. shellcheck.net is really useful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the latest version number:

```
cd /path/to/files
printf '%s\n' *r0102.tar.gz | cut -d_ -f2 |  sort -n -t. -k1,2 |tail -n1
```

If you want the file name:

```
cd /path/to/files
lastest=$(printf '%s\n' *r0102.tar.gz | cut -d_ -f2 |  sort -n -t. -k1,2 |tail -n1)
printf '%s\n' *${lastest}_r0102.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following which finds all the matching files, sorts the filenames, takes the last in that list, and then extracts the version from the filename.

```
#!/bin/bash
file_version=$(find ./directory -name "FileName*r0102.tar.gz" | sort | tail -n1 | sed -r 's/.*_(.+)_.*/\1/g')
echo ${file_version}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to parse the filename's version number prior to finding the actual filename.  Use *GNU* `ls`'s  `-v` (*natural sort of (version) numbers within text*) option:

```
ls -v FileName_[0-9.]*_r0102.tar.gz | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and thats worth working below script line, that You need.

```
echo `ls ./*.tar.gz | sort | sed  -n /[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]/p|tail -n 1`;
```